# How can I name a MapElements step in a Cloud Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Following the [dataflow docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#lightweight-dofns), I can name each step of a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline using `ParDo.named`:

```
PCollection<Integer> wordLengths = words.apply(
  ParDo
    .named("ComputeWordLengths")   // the transform name
    .of(new DoFn<String, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        c.output(c.element().length());
      }
    }));
```

If I use `MapElements` instead, however, the example in the documentation does not name the step:

```
PCollection<Integer> wordLengths = words.apply(
  MapElements.via((String word) -> word.length())
      .withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<Integer>() {});
```

How can I name this `MapElements` step?

I have several `MapElements` steps and I'm getting errors like this:

```
Mar 01, 2016 1:36:39 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline applyInternal
WARNING: Transform MapElements2 does not have a stable unique name. This will prevent updating of pipelines.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the name when you apply it. For instance:

```
words.apply("name", MapElements.via(...)) 
// instead of 
words.apply(MapElements.via(...))
```

See the JavaDoc on the [named apply method](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/values/PCollection.html#apply-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.PTransform-) for more details.